# call a SOAP service from wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, soap

I would like to call a Webservice from a wordpress page, and i would like to know how to.

To be more specific, i'm creating a wordpress form for one of my customers. This form must be composed of 3 input in first time, and when you add your familiars ( name, last name and e-mail) this is supposed to reveal some other fields if you already have an account on a specific other database.

We can access this database by a SOAP web service, my prob is : How can i consume a web service from a wordpress page ?
I tried to search how to do it on php, but no ideas of what i'm going to do.
The only way to check if those persons are stored on this database is to use this Webservice.

I tried to find some plugins or tips, or anything on the web, but all the answers are so blurry...or so old ( 10 years for a tutorial seem to be to old to work correctly i guess)

Can you help me ?

Comment: you can use `include('path/to/soapRequest.php')` in you template. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried few plugins so far, like: WP Simple Web Services, WPSOAP and another one called web service for wordpress, but they just seem to make wordpress's ressources available to call from a webservice (i precise that i can't pass by a json format, mainly because REST api is not an option for my customers ^^').

Comment: do you think that i can call it on a template page ? Or do i have to create a new php page ? I never used Webservices before this i have to admit it, but there might be a simple way right ?

Comment: Well you don't need to use a plugin if you have a working php that does it. Try to create a custom template and use `include` to load you php

Comment: I don't have a file, i have an URL that they gave me to grab the informations from.

Comment: You have to program a soap client, which retrieves the data from the endpoint url you 've got. There is no easy way to do so with wordpress. I guess the url you 've got looks something like `https://www.example.com/webservice?wsdl`. Based on that url you have to develop a soap client. Try to use php 's own `SoapClient` class. Include this client in a wordpress way by using the filter or hook which is provided by wordpress and fits your needs. There will be no ready to use wordpress plugin for your purpose.

Comment: you're right marcel, i have this type of url format.  So i guess you're also right, i have to developp a php client to grab the informations from webservices and then to include my page with include ('path to soap/client'). So thanks guys for those answers ! =)